# How to check multiple cookies are set in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I am checking a single cookie named "user" in my `.htaccess` file. If the cookie is set then redirect to `index.html` page while if cookie is not set then redirect to `index.php` page. I am not sure whether it is a proper approach of checking cookie existence but here's my `.htaccess` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But suppose if I have one more cookie named "login" then how do we check that in this `.htaccess` file?

Do I need to repeat same lines of above code for that particular cookie? Can we check multiple cookies in a single condition or line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, written based on your shown samples.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} user;? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} login;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

---

---

OR try within a single ruleset itself. Kindly make sure either you use above rules OR following rules only one at a time.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (user|login);? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !user;? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can we check multiple cookies in a single condition or line?

Yes sure you can use condition like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.(php|html)$ - [L,NC]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# execute when either of these cookies are set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (^|;)(user|login)= [NC]
RewriteRule .+ index.html?url=$0 [QSA,L]

# execute when neither of above cookies are set
RewriteRule .+ index.php?url=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Whenever I ask a question regarding htaccess, you almost every time contribute in giving me answer. But RavinderSingh13's solution looked me more simple and understandable. Sorry I couldn't follow through your htaccess rules.

Comment: It is absolutely fine to select whatever answer that works for you. I added 2 additional rules in your current setup so that you 1. Don't run into a rewrite loop 2. Avoid rewrite of resources file e.g. image, css, js files etc. Apart from this I can clarify anything else which is not clear to you.

Comment: Sure, thanks. I will try out your rules too when I get chance.